# phpThumb is not setting parameter – fltr[] usm

Tags: thumbnails, phpthumb

I am using Brett's [Mr. PHP thumb caching script](http://mrphp.com.au/blog/image-cache-using-phpthumb-and-modrewrite) along with phpThumb to create my thumbs. It works extremely well, except for one thing... I cannot get it to set and process the UnSharpMask filter.  The relevant part of the script looks like this:

```
// generate the thumbnail
require('../phpthumb/phpthumb.class.php');
$phpThumb = new phpThumb();
$phpThumb->setSourceFilename($image);
$phpThumb->setParameter('w',$width);
$phpThumb->setParameter('h',$height);
$phpThumb->setParameter('q','95'); // set the quality to 95%
$phpThumb->setParameter('fltr[]','usm|80|0.5|3'); // <--- THIS SHOULD SET THE USM FILTER
$phpThumb->setParameter('f',substr($thumb,-3,3)); // set the output file format

if (!$phpThumb->GenerateThumbnail()) {
    error('cannot generate thumbnail');
}
```

I'm guessing there's a problem with my syntax, since the fltr[] parameter requires brackets.  I have tried escaping the brackets like so: 'fltr[]' but that didn't work either.

I've used several other possible parameters with good success (zoom cropping, max height, max width, etc...)  Everything seems to work except the filters (including usm - UnSharpMask).

I don't get any errors.  It spits out thumbs all day long.  They're just not sharpened.

For reference, here's the [official phpThumb readme file](http://phpthumb.sourceforge.net/demo/docs/phpthumb.readme.txt) that discusses all the possible settings and filters.

Thanks for looking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after much trial, error, and aggravation, I finally discovered the solution buried in one of the demo files that come with phpThumb.

It's a matter of removing the brackets all together.  Basically changing this line:

```
$phpThumb->setParameter('fltr[]','usm|80|0.5|3');
```

to this:

```
$phpThumb->setParameter('fltr','usm|80|0.5|3');
```

After that, it's only a matter of tweaking the settings to get the desired amount of sharpness.